# Subsetting in R using OR condition with strings

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame with about 40 columns, the second column, data[2] contains the name of the company that the rest of the row data describes. However, the names of the companies are different depending on the year (trailing 09 for 2009 data, nothing for 2010).

I would like to be able to subset the data such that I can pull in both years at once. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do...

```
subset(data, data[2] == "Company Name 09" | "Company Name", drop = T)
```

Essentially, I'm having difficulty using the OR operator within the subset function.

However, I have tried other alternatives:

```
subset(data, data[[2]] == grep("Company Name", data[[2]]))
```

Perhaps there's an easier way to do it using a string function?

Any thoughts would be appreicated.

Comment: Did you mean subset(data, data[,2] == "Company Name 09" | data[,2] == "Company Name", drop = T)

Comment: Syntax, my worst enemy. Thanks Jonathan. That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all (as Jonathan done in his comment) to reference second column you should use either `data[[2]]` or `data[,2]`. But if you are using subset you could use column name: `subset(data, CompanyName == ...)`.

And for you question I will do one of:

```
subset(data, data[[2]] %in% c("Company Name 09", "Company Name"), drop = TRUE) 
subset(data, grepl("^Company Name", data[[2]]), drop = TRUE)
```

In second I use `grepl` (introduced with R version 2.9) which return logical vector with `TRUE` for match.

Comment: Thanks Marek, the second solution is much cleaner and simplifies the code. grepl isn't in my docs when I search ??string.

Comment: Hilarious thanks a lot Marek, did not even know subset accepts `%in%`. This saves a lot of cumbersome / error-prone typing with OR clauses. +1 !! my answer of the week so far!

Comment: What if the column name has a space? for instance "Company Name". Can we still use subset

Comment: @RockScience Yes. But you must use back-ticks. Something like `subset(data, 'Company Name'=="Name A")` (I can't use "true" back-ticks in comment so you must change it).

Comment: Can I ask a stupid question? What does the drop argument do? I didn't really get the description in the help.

Comment: @Lilith-Elina `drop=FALSE` prevent conversion to vector when one column left, `drop=TRUE` allow this conversion. Compare: `subset(cars, select=speed)` and `subset(cars, select=speed, drop=TRUE)`, first gives you `data.frame`, second numeric vector. Read more in `help("[.data.frame")`.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things:

1) Mock-up data is useful as we don't know exactly what you're faced with. Please supply data if possible. Maybe I misunderstood in what follows?

2) Don't use `[[2]]` to index your data.frame, I think [,"colname"] is much clearer

3) If the only difference is a trailing ' 09' in the name, then simply regexp that out:

```
R> x1 <- c("foo 09", "bar", "bar 09", "foo")
R> x2 <- gsub(" 09$", "", x1)
[1] "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo"
R>
```

Now you should be able to do your subset on the on-the-fly transformed data:

```
R> data <- data.frame(value=1:4, name=x1)
R> subset(data, gsub(" 09$", "", name)=="foo")
  value   name
1     1 foo 09
4     4    foo
R>
```

You could also have replace the name column with regexp'ed value.

Comment: Jonathan gave me the answer that I was looking for in a comment above. But your post solves another similar problem I was having. Thanks Dirk.